# Clicking content div inside overlay div also closes the popup

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a pop-up where the container is just a black background with some opacity, and then that div container contains the content of the popup.

Basically it looks something like:

```
<button (click)="showPopup = !showPopup">Open popup</button>

<div class="overlay-bg" (click)="showPopup = !showPopup" [ngClass]="showPopup ? 'is-active' : ''">
 <div class="content">Some content</div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks something like:

```
.overlay {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;

  &.is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    place-self: center;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

So basically, when the state is not active, it's not showing, and when `is-active` is enabled by clicking the button, the overlay + content is displayed. Now, what I would also like is that when clicking the background, the pop-up should close - which is does. However, the problem is, that the pop-up also closes when I just click the content - which it shouldn't since it should be somewhat interactive.

So how do I prevent the pop-up from closing when interacting with the content div ?

Comment: I don't know what this syntax is `(click)="showPopup = !showPopup"` but if you use plain javascript and add an event handler, you'll get `event` parameter. Inspect `event.target` to know from where click event originated. `if event.target === <overlay-bg-reference>` then only execute `showPopup = !showPopup`

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in stackblitz and share here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

The reason this happens is due to the event flow in javascript, which is the order in which events are handled. This is important when there are nested elements, like with your two divs ('overlay-bg' and 'content'). Modern browsers use **event bubbling** which means that the innermost child element handles the event first. The event then 'bubbles' and works its way outwards. In your case, the 'content' div must handle the event first. You do not want the pop-up to disappear when the 'content' div is clicked, but you do when the 'overlay-bg' div is clicked. Therefore you must find a way of stopping the event bubbling from occurring by capturing it with the onclick event on the 'content' div. This can be done by using the `stopPropagation()` method of the event object.

## Solution

To stop the event from bubbling upwards when the user clicks on the 'content' div, add an onclick event handler in the HTML:

```
 <div class="content" onclick="preventBubbling(event)">Some content</div>
```

Then, with JavaScript, you can use the `stopPropagation()` method of the event object which is passed as a parameter to the function. To achieve this, the function would look like this:

```
function preventBubbling(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

This stops the event from bubbling up to the parent div, so the click event is never triggered, and the pop-up does not hide (when the user clicks on the content div).

---

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event to the elements you don't want to be affected and just return false, for example:

```
 $(".content").click(function () {
       return false;
  });
```

**Make sure when you add this event, that the content doesn't have an anchor tag because it will disable it, meaning it won't direct you as it should, you will click it but no redirect will happen**